# CSS Layout Query

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to position a couple of elements on the page.

```
<div id='select'></div> // red div
<h5>Subheader</h5>
<div id='image'>Example of a DIV element with a background image:</div>  // green div
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqt4aosx/2/

The first one 'red div' is now sitting where I want to be, but when I try to position the sub header and 'green div' they appear to be lower down the page.

Ideally there shouldn't be such a gap between the bottom of the red div and the sub header.  The gap between the sub header and the Green div is fine.

Any ideas how I resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is created by `top: -90px;` in your jsfiddle.

I amended your style for the red box & floated the form to the left, i think this gives you the result you are after.

```
#form{
  float:left;
}

#select {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #d90036;
  width: 176px;
  height: 175px;
  margin-left:160px;
}
```

The spacing for the subheader can then be altered by using margin / padding on the `h5` tag as normal